# Individual studio count in a table

Tags: sql

I have table like this.

```
RETAIL_SKU  STUDIO_NAME REGION  MERCHANT    SOURCE_TYPE RETOUCH_LEVEL   

CCCF9X55FI  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCHB1Z8EE  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCFECJQ1I  LEJ1A           EU  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCH296DN0  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCEQR38LQ  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCHSC2X0I  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCA0IY4OU  BV-DE-RETAIL    EU  Buy VIP     Vendor  9   
CCCGX64C68  PCCL3B          NA  Buy VIP     Studio  9   
CCCG7U7W4O  CCRY1B          EU  Buy VIP     Studio  9
```

And am looking a result like this

```
STUDIO_NAME REGION
CCRY1B            3
PCCL3B            4
LEJ1A             1
BV-DE-RETAIL      1
```

This is what i tried .(But it throws error)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(STUDIO_NAME),COUNT(RETAIL_SKU) FROM Sheet7 WHERE MERCHANT='Buy VIP' AND RETOUCH_LEVEL=9
```

i just started to learn Sql so i have very minimal knowledge. Your assistance will be great help for me

**Updated**

```
str = "SELECT STUDIO_NAME,COUNT(*) REGION FROM [Sheet7$] WHERE MERCHANT='Buy VIP' AND RETOUCH_LEVEL=9 GROUP BY STUDIO_NAME"
     rsEx.Open str, ConEx, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    STUDIO_NAME,
    COUNT(*) REGION
FROM Sheet7 
WHERE MERCHANT='Buy VIP' AND 
    RETOUCH_LEVEL=9
GROUP BY STUDIO_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. the purpose of the query is to run on VBA . But when i ran the above query i got error .. see updated section